# prevent duplicate entries in $PATH

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

In regular way to add a directory to PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/new-directory
```

Now the problem is if you add a new directory to the PATH then it will be added without checking if it's already in the PATH or not.

For example:

```
echo $PATH
```

gives:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Now if I add `/usr/bin`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

Then PATH becomes:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin
```

So, if you can notice, now `/usr/bin` is repeated.

So, how can I add a new directory to the PATH without repeating?

Answer (score 7):

A short way is to use:

```
[[ ":$PATH:" =~ ":/new-directory:" ]] || PATH="/new-directory:$PATH"
```

Explanations:

- First command, the `[[` conditional command, is for test.
- The `=~` binary operator return 0 if the string from the right which is considered  an  extended  regular  expression matches the string from the left, and 1 otherwise.
- If the test is *not* passed (`/new-directory` was *not* found in PATH), thanks to the `||` logical OR control operator, the second command is executed: `PATH="/new-directory:$PATH"`.

Observations:

- You should always use quotes when you assign a string to a variable, even if the string is another variable: `PATH="/new-directory:$PATH"`.
- In general is better to add a new directory to the PATH environment variable in front to others directories, not after:  `PATH="/new-directory:$PATH"`. This because directories at the beginning of PATH take precedence over those that come later.

Answer (score 5):

I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Comment: I put the bash_path_funcs directory from this tarball under ~/.bash.d/ and `chmod +x` on all the scripts (except of course README) and then in my .bashrc I do ```for f in `find $HOME/.bash.d -type f -perm +111` ; do source "$f"; done```

Comment: You are supposed to actually read the `README` file, and invoke the functions the way the `README` says.

Comment: I did, and I do.  I was just adding the above comment to share a way to load the functions  upon shell startup.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's a good addition. However, I needed to replace `-perm +111` with `-executable` to just source all the executables. Now I can fill my bashrc with e.g. `addpath $HOME/.yarn/bin` without fear of duplication.

Comment: And, there's `uniqpath` to remove duplicates.

Comment: do duplicates do anything bad?

Comment: It's just that when you print them, which you frequently do to debug an issue finding an executable, the output is mode readable when shorter

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command:

```
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":/new-directory:"* ]]; then PATH=${PATH}:/new-directory; fi
```

Now for the example above:

```
echo $PATH
```

gives:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Now if I want to add /usr/bin:

```
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":/usr/bin:"* ]]; then PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin; fi
```

You can notice that PATH doesn't change:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

now to add other directory example /var/www

```
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":/var/www:"* ]]; then PATH=${PATH}:/var/www; fi
```

Then output of `echo $PATH` gives:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/www
```