# How to remove texlive from Path

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, .profile, texlive

I want to remove texlive from my PATH after deleting it with `rm -rf` command and I have deleted the path for texlive in .bashrc but when i run the command: `echo $PATH` I'm still seeing texlive in my path:

`/home/tonomo/anaconda3/bin:/home/tonomo/anaconda3/bin:/home/tonomo/anaconda3/bin:/home/tonomo/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/tonomo/.local/bin:/home/tonomo/bin`

Also I'm not sure why I have repeating paths in my path list, is this normal?

#### UPDATE

Answer provided by @Sebastian Stark was all I needed to fix this.

Comment: It is abnormal to have multiple copies of a directory in `$PATH`. Your `~/.bashrc` adds it - fix it there. `PATH` is set up at the beginning of  shell execution. See my answer at   https://askubuntu.com/questions/432217/prevent-duplicate-entries-in-path 
Junior Associate

613-567-4529 Ext. 23

Comment: I read you answer @waltinator but the link you posted there doesn't work. How exactly do I fix the path in `.bashrc` when I already tried deleting a directory in the PATH variable but the directory still shows when I `echo $PATH`?

Comment: My bad, I used links in my answer, but they went away. You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other places to look for the PATH variable are:

- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile.d/*`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Check all of them one by one for occurrences of the `PATH` variable and edit as appropriate.

Make sure to log out and in completely afterwards. Depending on how your PATH is set it is most likely that just restarting bash or the terminal is not enough! Most answers on editing bashrc will tell you it's enough to source it or exec bash or such. In most cases this is enough, but if you use `export PATH=/foo/bin:$PATH` it will never remove old components from PATH, because the variable is still set in the surrounding desktop environment.

Regarding the multiple paths for anaconda: Looks like a bug in their installer to me. You can simply remove all the duplicates.

Comment: The thing is I added the path for texlive by myself and I only added it to .bashrc so texlive should not be in any other location. How do I remove all the duplicates for anaconda? Is deleting them from .bashrc all I need? Also I'm not sure why I have to log in and out considering I made the change in .bashrc which is run when an interactive non-login shell (i.e. terminal) is opened. Closing and reopening the terminal should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: I've also checked and there it isn't in any other location

Comment: Can confirm a re-login worked, thanks @Sebastian Stark